# Row and column labels for matrix algebra in Lisp

Tags: matrix, lisp, common-lisp, linear-algebra

I am looking for a Lisp package for matrix algebra that shows the name-tags of every row and column along with the data, which makes the data a lot easier to read.

R does something like this:

```
                 George     Micheal      Maria
1999-01-04 1.0442238472 1427.447631  88.808903  
1999-01-05 0.9944458362 1441.538069  88.730143   
1999-01-06 1.0233398966 1472.594545  88.743269
```

Is anyone aware of a Lisp package for matrix algebra with such feature?

Comment: I have removed the R tag, since you don't ask about R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add row and column labels yourself with a simple wrapper:

```
(defclass data-table ()
  ((matrix :initarg :matrix
           :reader data-table-matrix)
   (row-labels :initarg :row-labels
               :reader data-table-row-labels)
   (column-labels :initarg :column-labels
                  :reader data-table-column-labels)))
```

Now, define a reading function to create such a table from a printed table and a writing function to write it.  You might use a method for `print-object` with `print-unreadable-object` for the latter:

```
(defmethod print-object ((object data-table) stream)
  (print-unreadable-object (object stream)
    (let ((matrix (data-table-matrix object))
          (row-names (data-table-row-names object)))
      (format stream "~%          ");
      (map nil
           (lambda (name)
             (format stream "~,10a" name))
           (data-table-column-names object))
      (dotimes (i (array-dimension matrix 0))
        (format stream "~,10~a" (elt row-names i))
        (dotimes (j (array-dimension matrix 1))
          (format stream "~,10a" (aref matrix i j)))))))
```

(Untested prototype.  I used `elt` and `map` so you can represent the row and column names as any sequence, but you might want to change that for efficiency.)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout: http://common-lisp.net/project/lisplab/

> Lisplab contains
>
> - Matlab-like matrix manipulation
> - Interfaces to BLAS and LAPACK
> - Interface to FFTW
> - Numerical integration through QUADPACK
> - Special functions from SLATEC
> - Many Lisplab-specific routines for linear algebra, postscript output, PGM output, Fast Fourier Transform (native Common Lisp), infix math, etc.